# Generate Angular 2 Production-"Folder" with AOT-compilation

Tags: angular, rollupjs, angular2-aot

I have an Angular2 Application that runs locally on a lite server with jit as well as aot compilation.

For aot i followed the tutorial on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html. Now i want to host the application on a apache server.
However it seems that i have some configuration issues in my project.
I have the compiled aot folder with subfolders node_moduels and app + dist/build.js.
So far so good. I thought that copying the folders aot + dist and the files index.html (referencing build.js as in the tutorial) + styles.css to the apache server should work. However this leads to wrong references when running the app.

I get 404 for all files referenced in index.html, example:
http://apacheserverurl/dist/build.js

The same problem occors when i open the index.html by hand in a browser. Shouldn't this work since i compiled all the javascript and html files?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I had to change the base-tag href to "./".